# How to create an XDocument given an XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement, xmlwriter

We have a method that writes XML into an XmlWriter, we use this to generate a stream of XML directly without having to go via some form of DOM. However there are occasions where we do want to create a DOM. One approach would be to always build a DOM and to stream from that (to cover both requirements), but we like the performance of writing XML directly. Therefore we want to build a DOM from an XmlWriter.

See [How to create a XmlDocument using XmlWriter in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346995/how-to-create-a-xmldocument-using-xmlwriter-in-net) for an example of how to create an XmlDocument from an XmlWriter, albeit using a slightly off-piste code pattern. Are there similar options if I want an XDocument (or XElement subtree) instead?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [XContainer.CreateWriter Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.createwriter.aspx):

> **XContainer.CreateWriter Method**
>
> Creates an XmlWriter that can be used to add nodes to the XContainer.

Both `XDocument` and `XElement` are XContainers.

*Example:*

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    // Do this directly 
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    writer.WriteElementString("foo", "bar");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    // or anything else you want to with writer, like calling functions etc.
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, the only thing to consider from a perfomance point of view is that on writer.Close() the Add() function of XDocument is used to add the complete XML.

Comment: @Marco. Can you explain that a bit further? Looks like I get an XmlWellFormedWriter returned so not sure how that is connected to the XDocument and therefore what happens when the writer is closed.

Comment: OK I see it. XNodeBuild is used under the hood and actually just uses a StringBuilder to build an XML string and then do one big parse at the end. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: where is the given XmlWriter?