# IO exception (XML) - the process cannot access the file because it is used by another process

Tags: c#, xml, exception, io, ioexception

I created a class called Shipment which has the following static method:

```
public static void WriteShipment(Shipment s, string path)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";
    XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings);
    w.WriteStartDocument();
    w.WriteStartElement("Shipment");
    w.WriteStartElement("id");
    w.WriteString(s.id);
    w.WriteEndElement();
    Address.WriteAddress(s.from, path);
    Address.WriteAddress(s.to, path);
    Date.WriteDate(s.receiveDate, path);
    Date.WriteDate(s.deliverDate, path);
    w.WriteStartElement("sum");
    w.WriteValue(s.sum);
    w.WriteEndElement();
    w.WriteStartElement("currency");
    w.WriteString(s.currency);
    w.WriteEndElement();
    w.WriteStartElement("paid");
    w.WriteValue(s.paid);
    w.WriteEndElement();
    w.WriteEndElement();
    w.WriteEndDocument();
    w.Close();
}
```

I'm trying to write a method which receives an instance of the `Shipment` class and creates an XML file with its details.

Some of Shipment's fields are of type `Address` and `Date`, which are other classes I created. They also have static methods which write the details of an instance, received as a parameter, into an XML file.

The `WriteAddress` and `WriteDate` methods work perfectly well, but when I try to invoke them inside the `WriteShipment` method, I get the following exception during run-time -

> "the process cannot access file because it is used by another process"

I figured out it happens because `WriteAddress` and `WriteDate` are trying to write into the same file `WriteShipment` already writes into (since they all share the same path).

Is there a way to overcome this? Any other solution I've tried proved to be futile or caused other problems.

Comment: Use try and catch and using...Check this link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346995/how-to-create-a-xmldocument-using-xmlwriter-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is likely because the `WriteAddress` and `WriteDate` methods are attempting to open the file that is already opened.

When you make the call to `XmlWriter.Create`, the file is being 'locked' such that it can only be written to using the `w` variable, and it remains locked until you call `w.Close()`.

Your best option would be to pass the `w` variable as an argument to the `WriteAddress` and `WriteDate` methods and that to write to the file.

Also, as a suggestion, consider putting your code into a [using block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it). That way, if any of the methods throw an exception, you won't be left with the file still locked.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to pass my XmlWriter as a parameter before, but then I had no way to indent it and all the XML code in the created file was written in a single line. Do you know how can I both pass my XmlWriter as a parameter and make it indented (which the settings variable in the beginning of the code currently does)?

Comment: I second Ryan S. Use the try catch and using blocks. Also if you are now having formatting issues you might want to update your question or start a new question if your runtime exception no longer is an issue. Be sure and mark the answer that solved your problem ;)

Comment: The indenting should work automatically. The `XmlWriter` contains the settings for indenting that you provided when you created the `XmlWriter` object. Try it again, and if it still doesn't work, please post your code for the WriteAddress method.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to fix this. Here are some suggestions.

1. Close the `XmlWriter` in `WriteShipment` before you execute the `WriteDate` and `WriteAddress` methods. Reopen it after you're done
2. Instead of opening and writing to the file in `WriteData/Address` just return a string and then write it to the file in `WriteShipment`. Is there any case where you need to write directly using `WriteData/Address`, and not as part through the `WriteShipment` method?